# Spring Boot - Identify resources under resource folder

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot App. I am trying to read few files that I have placed under main/resources folder.  I see that Spring Boot automatically reads application.properties under resources folder. However it doesn't seem to read other xml / text files that I have placed under resources folder.

```
Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("removeNs.xslt"));
```

Should I add any additional configuration for the program to automatically read all the files under resources folder without having to explicitly provide the path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("removeNs.xslt").getFile());
```

This should work.

Thanks @Edwin for mentioning a more robust solution:

```
File file = new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("removeNs.xslt").getFile());
```

Comment: I would suggest a `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource()` since the class loading technique in the example sometimes fails within the application context.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo Good suggestion. Added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks EdwinDalorzo & Terry Li!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that you want to read specific files under resources folder using

`@PropertySource` annotation.

you can specify multiple property sources using

```
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource(),
    @PropertySource()
})
```